# "Revoke" and "Download" buttons for APNS certificates are disabled

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications

On the 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles' page in the Apple Account Developer site, I want to revoke and download certain certificates. I can't, because if I'm logged in with an Admin role, the page isn't accessible, and if I'm logged in with a Developer role, the buttons are disabled:

[image: Revoke and download buttons]

Comment: only admin has power to revoke certificate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Faced This Issue Before 2 Days Ago. This Happens When You have Developer Privileges. Plz Go To Itunes Connect "User And Access" Change The Roles. Plz Open  Attach Image.

If You have developer Privileges you can't download, Revoke Certificate, as well as not add UDID.  For More Info :- https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/ [image: Open Image]

If You need full access then Admin privileges are available.

[image: Roles For APNS]

Comment: I had NoScript blocking this but then I enabled it and I saw it. Thanks